# Ubuntu 13.04 Dark Screen on Live Pendrive

Tags: 13.04, live-usb, brightness, usb-drive

I have a 2-3 year old gateway laptop that I wiped the hard drive to.  I tried installing Ubuntu 13.04 from a DVD and that didn't work, but that isn't the question I'm asking.  I am now trying to install Ubuntu 13.04 from a live pendrive I created using the Universal USB Installer.  It loads everything just fine, but when it loads the home screen, it is so dark, I cannot see well enough to navigate.  Is there an Ubuntu-specific key combination to turn up the screen brightness or anything else I should try?

Edit - I tried using the fn + up/down arrow keys for brightness and they did not work.

Comment: Did you use xbacklight?

Comment: I have no idea what that is, but I did manage to fix the problem by hooking my laptop to my TV then navigating to the brightness settings

Answer (score 0):

Usually all the laptops today have a "Fn" or a function key, which can be used in combination with another key to control screen brightness.

I haven't used a gateway ever before but i assume there must be one of those keys in the top row which has a brightness icon.

**`Fn + Up(Arrow Key)`**
 would be my best guess.

Or Fn + Brightness Up key

Some examples of brightness keys:
[image]

Hope that helps you.

Comment: I tried using that and it didn't work.  Is it supposed to?

Comment: Hi @Pomg , Yes they are supposed to work. I would also try hunting for gateway drivers for linux for these special keys.

Comment: The keys seemed to work after I actually installed the operating system.  When I ran it off of a live thumb drive, they didn't work, but once I hooked it up to a TV, I was able to see what I was doing well enough to install Ubuntu onto my computer, from there I was finally able to use the Fn + Up/Down arrow keys to control brightness.